# First Order Logic: Truth Value of a statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have to find the truth values of the given statements in the domain of discourse $D = \{2,3,4\}$.

$\text{I}.\ p : \exists x \forall y(x^2 < 2y)$

$\text{II}.\ q : \forall y \exists x (x = y+1 \;\;\lor\;\; x = 2y)$

I know the first one is false because although the given statement is true for $y = 3, 4$ but for $y = 2$ there is no $x$ which makes the statement true.

In the second statement also, it is true for $y = 2, 3$ but false for $y = 4$. So since one element of domain does not satisfy the statement the truth value should be false. But the answer in my textbook says its true.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your reasoning. Are you sure you read/wrote the question and answer correctly? If this is the case, then the textbook is incorrect.

Comment: @user400188 Yeah the question is correct. It might be wrong in the textbook. I'll verify my solution. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing here ?

That textbooks can be *wrong* on occasion.

That is all.